# Automatic casting of data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am interested in a method that automatically converts a data frame consisting of factor columns (like df) to the best possible type, similar to what read.table creates (like df2). One possibility could be to write the data frame into a string and read it back in with read.table. Are there other ones?

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(" 1"," 2", " 3"),b=c("a","b","c"),c=c(" 1.0", "NA", " 2.0"),d=c(" 1", "B", "2"))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1"," 2"," 3": 1 2 3
 $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ c: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1.0"," 2.0",..: 1 3 2
 $ d: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1","2","B": 1 3 2
> df2 <- with(df, data.frame(a=as.integer(a),b=b,c=as.numeric(c),d=as.character(d), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3
 $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ c: num  1 3 2
 $ d: chr  " 1" "B" "2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function that `read.table` makes use of: `type.convert`.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(" 1"," 2", " 3"), b=c("a","b","c"), 
                 c=c(" 1.0", "NA", " 2.0"), d=c(" 1", "B", "2"))
str(df)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1"," 2"," 3": 1 2 3
#  $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
#  $ c: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1.0"," 2.0",..: 1 3 2
#  $ d: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1","2","B": 1 3 2
df[] <- lapply(df, function(y) type.convert(as.character(y)))
df
#   a b  c  d
# 1 1 a  1  1
# 2 2 b NA  B
# 3 3 c  2  2
str(df)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ a: int  1 2 3
#  $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
#  $ c: num  1 NA 2
#  $ d: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1","2","B": 1 3 2
```

(But I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for...)

---

***Update***: If you wanted to create a `colClasses` type function, perhaps you can try a function like this. Unlike your question title, this is not "automatic", but it does allow you to specify the column class for each column instead of leaving it to `type.convert` to decide.

```
toColClasses <- function(inDF, colClasses) {
  if (length(colClasses) != length(inDF)) stop("Please specify colClasses for each column")
  inDF[] <- lapply(seq_along(colClasses), function(y) {
    if (colClasses[y] == "") inDF[y] <- inDF[[y]]
    else {
      FUN <- match.fun(colClasses[y])
      inDF[y] <- suppressWarnings(FUN(as.character(inDF[[y]])))
    }
  })
  inDF
}
```

You would use it as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(" 1"," 2", " 3"), b = c("a","b","c"), 
                 c = c(" 1.0", "NA", " 2.0"), d = c(" 1", "B", "2"))

df2 <- toColClasses(df, c("as.integer", "", "as.numeric", "as.character"))
df2
#   a b  c  d
# 1 1 a  1  1
# 2 2 b NA  B
# 3 3 c  2  2
str(df2)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ a: int  1 2 3
#  $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
#  $ c: num  1 NA 2
#  $ d: chr  " 1" "B" "2"
```

You would have to do some more work on the function to get it to accept a wider range of `as...` functions though.